# Regular Expression get last item

Tags: regex, cocoa

I'm new to regular expressions so forgive me if this is really basic. I have a string like: `something "some item" something "another item"`and an expression:`".*"`. When I run it I get `"some item" something "another item"` but really all I want it `"another item"`. Is it possible to modify the expression to do that? It's going to be used via [RegExKit](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/).

Thanks

Comment: Please specify the programming language you're using regex with.

Comment: What distinguishes `"another item"` from, say, `something "another item"`? Are you looking for the second quoted substring?

Comment: Im looking for the last quoted substring no matter how many there are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the single example you've provided, this will work:

```
("[^"]*")$
```

It matches everything between a pair of double quotes, including the quotes, at the end of the input.

---

> Im looking for the last quoted substring no matter how many there are.

In that case, the above does not necessarily do what you want. Try this:

```
.*("[^"]*")
```

See [@mhyfrtiz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877452/regular-expression-get-last-item/6877536#6877536) for an explanation of the `.*` part.

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
.*"(.*)"
```

This makes use of the fact that the `*` quantifier is greedy, so the first `.*` will consume the entire text. After that the regex engine backtracks (i.e. traverses the string backwards from the end) until the last occurrence of `".*"` in the string matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
"[^"]*"$
```

should work for most languages, including JavaScript;